# Invalid input result from ios_command prevents stdout from registering in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, cisco-ios

I am having an issue running the ios_command module with Ansible. I am attempting to execute multiple commands and have the output stored to a variable.

It works perfectly except when one of the commands is unavailable on a Cisco switch and returns "Invalid input detected". If this happens, none of the output from any of the commands is stored to the variable.

Here's a very simple example:

```
  - name: "Running commands" 
    ios_command:
      commands:
        - show version
        - show run
    register: data_output
    ignore_errors: yes
```

In an ideal situation, both show version and show run return usable output and are thus stored and usable at data_output.stdout[0] and data_output.stdout[1].

However, when 'show run' is unavailable on a switch, I receive the following error and nothing is stored:

```
TASK [Running commands] *******************************************
fatal: [40.27.254.12]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "show run\\r\\n                   ^\\r\\n% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.\\r\\n\\r\\nR022DC3N5701>"}
...ignoring

TASK [Debug output] ************************************************************
ok: [40.27.254.12] => {
    "data_output": {
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": true, 
        "msg": "show run\\r\\n                   ^\\r\\n% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.\\r\\n\\r\\nR022DC3N5701>"
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to mitigate this? I need to run multiple IOS commands on hundreds of switches. Some will work fine, some will return output like we see above where a command is unavailable to be run.

Comment: It is likely that the first command didn't run, either.  Put each command in a different task.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is an authentication problem. Try to use the same credential to log on to the device and try "sh run" and see.

If that is the case and you are using TACAS+ for authentication, please check if TACAS+ allow the command for the account or give the privilege level for the user.

If the credential is a local account, you may need to further enter the enable password before "sh run". Fix it either:

1. Add "enable" and "{enable password}" before any command

   ```
   -enable
   -{enable password}
   ```
2. Config the user privilege in all devices to avoid password:

   ```
   Router(config)#username {username} privilege 15
   ```